# Unable to view some language fonts in Debian 8.2

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, fonts

[image]
They appear as small square boxes.

My distro: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `apt-get install fonts-indic`.    The package description says:

```
Description-en: Meta package to install all Indian language fonts. This metapackage merely depends on the various free Indian language font packages available in Debian. Use this if you want fonts for every Indian language.
 .
 The following metapackages will be pulled down as dependency which will inturn pull down real font packages.
   * fonts-beng
   * fonts-deva
   * fonts-gujr
   * fonts-guru
   * fonts-knda
   * fonts-mlym
   * fonts-orya
   * fonts-pagu
   * fonts-taml
   * fonts-telu
```

Comment: please have a look at this question and please answer if you can http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236965/fonts-problem-with-debian-8-2