# Fonts problem with Debian 8.2

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, fonts

[image][image]

On some websites fonts look like as above.It,s happening in all browsers from iceweasel to chromium.
My distro:Debian 8.2 with gnome 3.14.1
Graphics:Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset

Comment: What is the name of the fonts of the misbehaving websites?

Comment: What fonts packages, did you installed?

Comment: @Ortomala Lokni I have attached the info about my fonts.

Comment: Try to install ttf-liberation fonts: `sudo apt-get install ttf-liberation`.

Comment: No improvement!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Disabling Hinting in the fonts seems to resolve the issue.